# Receiving end of Cordova file upload

Tags: php, cordova, file-transfer

I'm working on uploading a file to a server using the cordova-file-transfer plugin. I know my file Upload works when using the browser to select a file yet I'm not entirely sure with the app since it's a relatively new way of doing it for me without form submissions.

EDIT: The below code is modified and is what was successful for me at the time after following @kay27's advice. The solution was to use params to POST the data to the awaiting upload handler.

```
function uploadFile() {

function success(r) {
    console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
    console.log("Response  = " + r.response);
    console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
}

function fail(error) {
    console.log("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
    console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
    console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
}

/* Destination of file */
var url = encodeURI("http://someURL/yourPHPUploadFile.php");
var fileURI = "file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.yourPackageName/fileToUpload";

var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey = "file";
options.fileName = fileURI.substr(fileURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
options.mimeType = "text/csv";

var params = new Object();
//allows you to POST the data to server side script
params.fileName = options.fileName; 
options.params = params;

var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(fileURI, url, success, fail, options);
}
```

The edited PHP form

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

$location       = "uploads/";
$uploadfile     = $_POST['fileName'];
$uploadfilename = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

if (move_uploaded_file($uploadfilename, $location . '/' . $uploadfile)) {
    echo 'File successfully uploaded!';
} else {
    echo 'Upload error!';
}
?>
```

Comment: Take a look at this way of defining params: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10851122/5920627

Comment: @kay27 thanks a million, the newer method of defining params did the trick. Tested it out there and the file is uploading !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my particular issue, the newer way of defining the params worked. The solution can be seen here on [Simon MacDonald's answer](http://%20stackoverflow.com/a/10851122/5920627). I've edited the code above with the final solution that allowed me to upload.